# Selenium locators - Div elements having the same class

Tags: selenium, classname

I am trying to access an element with the same class name. Please look at my page structure, it's something like this:

```
<div class="class-results-list-container" >
<div class="accordionWrapper">
<div class="accordionWrapper">
   <div class="accordion-header-wrapper">
   <div class="accordion-header padded-container">
   <div class="accordion-header-left">
   <div class="acc-head-left-wrapper">
   <div class="acc-head-left-row">
   <div class="heading-text">**RAMBO**</div>
   <div class="same-game-multi-notification-wrapper hidden">
   <div class="accordion-helptext"/>
   </div>
   </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="accordion-header-right">
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="accordion-content hidden" style="display: block;">
     </div>
<div class="accordionWrapper">
<div class="accordionWrapper">
<div class="accordionWrapper">
<div class="accordionWrapper">
<div class="accordionWrapper">
```

Comment: How about providing actual code?

Comment: <div class="class-results-list-container" >
<div class="accordionWrapper">
<div class="accordionWrapper">
   <div class="accordion-header-wrapper">
   <div class="accordion-header padded-container">
   <div class="accordion-header-left">
   <div class="acc-head-left-wrapper">
   <div class="acc-head-left-row">
   <div class="heading-text">**RAMBO**</div>
   <div class="same-game-multi-notification-wrapper hidden">

Comment: how about putting that in your question inside a snippet? That is unreadable.

Comment: I am new here , I am not sure what I am doing new to stack overflow sorry

Comment: I am tyring to click and element with the same class name How can I generate a xpath using index

Comment: You should trying using Google... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: What you mean by same class name ? The element should be unique to click on. Are you trying to get path with a mixture of class name ?

Comment: How about adding the code u have tried so far?

Comment: Which element you want to locate

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. From your html I assume that you could be interested to the text in

```
<div class="heading-text">**RAMBO**</div>
```

If is this, you can use the xpath `"//div[@class='heading-text']"`.

Java:

```
    WebElement wl= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='heading-text']"));
    System.out.println(wl.getText());
```

Python:

```
text=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='heading-text']")
print(text.text)
```

If, for some reason, you need also to check the text in this element, you can use

```
"//div[@class='heading-text'] [text()='**RAMBO**']"
```